# Distributing "closed" application on app store

Tags: deployment, app-store

Our company made application for ios for some clothing business. We would like for this app, to be widely available, so anyone on appstore can download it, but wouldn't be able to do anything useful unless he has corporate email and password (which is assigned by us (my team)). This app doesn't include payments, notifications, deep linking. The idea is, that we tell workers to go download this app on appstore (or give them link) and then send them email and password, so that they can start using this app. We tried deploying it to appstore, but they rejected it. We also tried with Enterprise, but they rejected it, because our company isn't big enough.

This is our first appstore app and we are a bit green in all this.

What are our options? For record, we are based in EU (Slovenia).

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: When Apple Rejects an apple in their App review process they would inform why they rejected it , can you share that reason so that if would help us understand the error and provide suggestions

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JK6s9a7.png this is what we received

Comment: Please Have a Look at https://www.apple.com/business/it/ or get in call with apple support team